# Tutorial on stochastic simulation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, simulation, stochastic, stochastic-process

I'd like to use Haskell for stochastic simulation, but I don't know how. I've read Hutton's 'Programming in Haskell', and I'm comfortable writing deterministic functional programs. However, I don't know how to start writing stochastic simulations of the sort that are easy in imperative languages like R or python. Is there a tutorial or primer on this that I could read, or can anyone provide some tips on getting started?

Answer (score 7):

There's a nice self-contained paper [Erwig and Kollmansberger: Functional Pearls - Probabilistic Functional Programming in Haskell](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/PFP_JFP06.pdf) on this topic. I used this as a starting point for writing a natural language processor based on Hidden Markov Models in Haskell. There's a [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/probability) that is based on this paper, which also seems to provide a basic interface to R plotting.

There's also an [entry](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Probabilistic_Functional_Programming) on the HaskellWiki with more links to hackage. In particular, the [ProbabilityMonads](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ProbabilityMonads) package might be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you - that looks interesting.

Answer (score -1):

http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#the-list-monad

This small section in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) talks about using the List monad and functor functions to easily deal with non-determinism. May be a little simplistic depending on what your needs are, but make good use of the tools that are already in the standard library.